# delete the always last row in angular-reactive -form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a reactive form in angular with the ability to dynamically delete rows in a form
how to delete the last row of index when user click on any row
using angular reactive form

Comment: Please post you code, it will avoid useless back and forth comments and guesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the last row by using the array length.

`this.getter.removeAt(this.getter.length-1)`

The getter is your formArray

Comment: Not a best JS code to remove array's last element. Also Op didn't say they use form arrays

Comment: He mentioned index so I presumed he is talking about a form array  , then what's the best code to remove the form array last item ?

Comment: There are many: array.splice(-1), =array.pop(), array.slice(0, -1), etc

Comment: yes , and why would it be better to use those instead of the specific removeAt() fn to remove elements from a formArray?

Comment: But the issue is not your use of js, but the afact that the question is unclear, lacks [mre] and you still answering. it is absolutely clear that this will make a lot of additional comments/questions. It is better to flag the question unclear and wait until the Op complies with SO rules/standards

Comment: SO is not a forum, neither a chat, but wiki style platform. It is not about users, but content. We all should contribute to a better quality knowledge resource, not just trublooting some low quality posters any issu